# RecyclerView add/delete animation while keeping ID's updated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView cards that I can add on position 0 (on top) and remove any card on the list. Thing is, every card has a "more options" button that shows a PopupMenu referencing to each card. See screenshot: 
[image: rc demo]

Thing is, if I want an animation, I need to use `adapter.notifyItemInserted(0)` upon adding, `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)` upon deleting. BUT, if I don't use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, the other card's ID's won't get updated and if I try expanding the PopupMenu or deleting any other card, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because I am trying to use an ID that doesn't exist anymore (in the case of deleting a card).

In sum, I am looking to notify single item actions to the RecyclerView while keeping the entire RV cards updated.

*I tried `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, arrayList.size())` but it acts the same as `notifyDataSetChanged()`*

Comment: Then obviously your ID is wrongly choosen ... others ID should not change when you are deleting one item(ID should be stable)

Comment: @Selvin I am not manually setting the ID's.

Comment: Show your code if you want to receive help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` in any place in your code where the operation is async or initiated by an event. In such a case, the `position` that has been passed onto the `onBindViewHiolder` would not be valid when the async callback is called upon on an event like a user click. In any other place it is safe to use the passed `position`.

Just to note, `adapter.notifyItemInserted(0)` or `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)` won't cause other recyclerview to be rebound. Just their viewholder position would be updated. That's for optimization and the reason why `position` is stale

Comment: Thank you for the insight. It's working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are using parameter **position** in your:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
```

of adapter. Try to use

```
holder.getAdapterPosition()
```

instead. This should solve your problem.